# Is $\Sigma_n^p$-SAT a complete problem for the $\Sigma_n^p$ class with polytime or with logspace reductions?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

Here I define $\Sigma_n^p$-SAT to be the problem of deciding if a boolean formula in prenex normal form with $n$ alternating quantifiers, starting with $\exists$, is satisfiable.

I found several mentions of complete problems for the classes of the polynomial hierarchy, but could not find if the completeness was taken with respect to polytime or logspace reductions.